# C Language priorities precedence

Tags: c

Recently I came across this program
x=3*4%5/2
In an arithmetic expression, the order of precedecne will be multiplication,division and modulus.
If we evaluate the expression, answer should be 0 but the answer is 1. Please explain

Comment: You are mistaken in thinking modulus will be performed last. It has the same precedence as the other multiplicative operators (`*` `/` `%` are all equal).

Comment: Operator precedence in C is well-documented. Seems to me your assignment was intended to be completed by you, not us. Please do your own homework. If you're having difficulties, ask your instructor for help; they're being paid to teach you. If you're simply not willing to make the effort, talk to your guidance counselor about finding a more appropriate course of study.

Answer (score 1):

1. Look up the C operator precedence table [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).
2. Note that `* / %` all have the same precedence and left-to-right associativity.
3. Evaluate from left to right: `3*4%5/2 = (((3*4)%5)/2) = 1`

Personally, I have a rule that if I have *any* uncertainty about precedence, I use parentheses to group. Relying on operator precedence is unwise: it can very between languages and styles of mathematics. A good programmer/mathematician tries to ensure that their code will evaluate as intended and also acts to clearly communicate this intention to others: parentheses eliminate ambiguity.

Answer (score -2):

The answer will be 1 only. 3*4=12, 12%5=2, 2/2=1

So the answer will be 1.

You will get 0 if you perform the operation from right. But thats not correct. When *, %, / are there which are of equal precedence, the first operation will be done by selecting the leftmost operator. So here we choose *. Then next comes %. After that /.